# How do I wrap my delete queries in a transaction in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I can remove document x from collection x, then remove document y from collection y, but if something goes wrong, rollback everything. Based on the documentation, DocumentationReference.delete() is basically the only way to delete a document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [`Transaction.delete(DocumentReference)` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#delete) to delete a document in a transaction.

So to transactionally delete all cities with a population < 100K (modified from the [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)):

```
var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    var count = 0;
    return transaction.get(citiesRef).then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          if (doc.data().population <= 1000000) {
            transaction.delete(doc.ref);
            count = count + 1;
          }
        });
    });
}).then(function(count) {
    console.log("Deleted cities ", count);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the [batch method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), as in:

```
let batch = db.batch()

batch.deleteDocument(documentXref)
batch.deleteDocument(documentYref)

batch.commit() { error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Note that this works even when offline. Thus if you want the operation to fail in that case, you should use the transaction approach.